# Proving that a function is a $C^\infty$ submanifold in $\Bbb{R}^2$ of dimension 1

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry

> We need to prove that for all $c\in\Bbb{R}$ the set $\{x\in\Bbb{R}\,\colon\, g(x)=c\, \}$ is a $C^\infty$ submanifold ($g\,\colon\,\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow \Bbb{R};(x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_1^3-x_2^3$) in $\Bbb{R}^2$ of dimension 1.

We've already proven that $g$ is a surjective $C^\infty$ function, and that it is a submersion  at every point $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$.

We believe that we need to use the Submersion Theorem. Any hints?

Comment: So, you've already proven everything, haven't you? (well, except for the silly case $c=0$ which is obvious). What do you think you're missing?